# Variable definition are separate from assignment in bash

Tags: bash, shell

The project I'm working on right now contains the same idiom again and again:

```
local cur_ts= ; cur_ts=$( date +%s )
```

They do it only for variables which values are calculated via `$()`.

```
local name=$1
local value=$2
local pair="$name => $value"
local server= ; server=$( hostname )
```

Looks like it makes some sense, at least according to the previous author. What is it?

Comment: Are you asking what is the meaning of $1.. $name.. $(hostname)?

Comment: Looks like someone copied and pasted it over and over, there should be no issue doing `local server=$(hostname)`, except  `bash` has a variable `HOSTNAME` anyway!

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: Well, looks like there _is_ an issue. @Inian, thanks for pointing out the other question.